# Create file and directories at the same time

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a blank file and its directories.

I have tried to use `cd. > foo\bar.txt` but it wont also make the directory.

Thank you.

Comment: What is stopping you doing it with two commands? _you've used the [tag:batch-file] tag, which can easily have multiple lines which can be grouped together for a sequence of commands_. `MD "foo" 2>Nul` followed by `CD.>"foo\bar.txt"`. You could even, if you wish, join the two commands together on one line, _with an ampersand_: `MD "foo" 2>Nul&CD.>"foo\bar.txt"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can suggest is to mkdir first and then crate file, in fact it's 2 instructions but you can execute it in one line

`mkdir test& cd. > test\test.txt`